# Presence of (-) hyphen in folder name restricts the use of image present in it

Tags: html

I was working with the image tag in HTML.I had a line in my file:

```
<img src="Static_Content/img1.png"/>
```

The code rendered the image in the browser. However, when i changed the folder name to Static-Content the image was not rendered. The equivalent line of code was changed to:

```
<img src="Static-Content/img1.png"/>
```

I am curious to know as to how the introduction of - in the folder name restricted the use of the image. Also, what are the other restrictions ?

Comment: My tests worked for both local and hosted files.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: just out of interest try something like "random123t/img1.png" Im thinking that it is got to do with allowed paths for content rather than the location/name.

Comment: hi @isherwood , the console had the following error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND